# Error in creating hibernate criteria for Embedded table

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have following classes in my project.

Employee class

```
@XmlRootElement
@Entity
@Table(name = "emp", catalog = "emps")
public class Employee implements java.io.Serializable {

    //other entity variables
    private Set<Title> titles = new HashSet<Title>(0);


    @XmlTransient
    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Title.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "employee", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    public Set<Title> getTitles() {
        return this.titles;
    }

    public void setTitles(Set<Title> titles) {
        this.titles = titles;
    }

}
```

Title

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "titles", catalog = "emps")
public class Title implements java.io.Serializable {

    private TitleId id;
    private Employee employee;
    private Date fromDate;
    private Date toDate;

    public Title() {
    }

    public Title(TitleId id, Employee employee) {
        this.id = id;
        this.employee = employee;
    }

    public Title(TitleId id, Employee employee, Date toDate) {
        this.id = id;
        this.employee = employee;
        this.toDate = toDate;
    }

    @EmbeddedId
    @AttributeOverrides({
            @AttributeOverride(name = "empNo", column = @Column(name = "emp_no", nullable = false)),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "title", column = @Column(name = "title", nullable = false, length = 50)),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "fromDate", column = @Column(name = "from_date", nullable = false, length = 10)) })
    public TitleId getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(TitleId id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    //rest of the code

}
```

Title Id

```
@Embeddable
public class TitleId implements java.io.Serializable {

    private int empNo;
    private String title;
    private Date fromDate;

    public TitleId() {
    }

    public TitleId(int empNo, String title, Date fromDate) {
        this.empNo = empNo;
        this.title = title;
        this.fromDate = fromDate;
    }

    @Column(name = "emp_no", nullable = false)
    public int getEmpNo() {
        return this.empNo;
    }

    public void setEmpNo(int empNo) {
        this.empNo = empNo;
    }

    @Column(name = "title", nullable = false, length = 50)
    public String getTitle() {
        return this.title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    @Column(name = "from_date", nullable = false, length = 10)
    public Date getFromDate() {
        return this.fromDate;
    }

    public void setFromDate(Date fromDate) {
        this.fromDate = fromDate;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if ((this == other))
            return true;
        if ((other == null))
            return false;
        if (!(other instanceof TitleId))
            return false;
        TitleId castOther = (TitleId) other;

        return (this.getEmpNo() == castOther.getEmpNo())
                && ((this.getTitle() == castOther.getTitle()) || (this
                        .getTitle() != null && castOther.getTitle() != null && this
                        .getTitle().equals(castOther.getTitle())))
                && ((this.getFromDate() == castOther.getFromDate()) || (this
                        .getFromDate() != null
                        && castOther.getFromDate() != null && this
                        .getFromDate().equals(castOther.getFromDate())));
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        int result = 17;

        result = 37 * result + this.getEmpNo();
        result = 37 * result
                + (getTitle() == null ? 0 : this.getTitle().hashCode());
        result = 37 * result
                + (getFromDate() == null ? 0 : this.getFromDate().hashCode());
        return result;
    }

}
```

I need to create a criteria to find the first name, last name and title of the users. The first name and last names are working fine in my criteria. The following code shows how I create my criteria for titles. "jobTitle" is a parameter that I'm passing to it.

```
Criteria employeeSearchCriteria = getSession().createCriteria(Employee.class);
employeeSearchCriteria.setFirstResult(0);
employeeSearchCriteria.setMaxResults(6);
employeeSearchCriteria.createAlias("titles.TitleId", "titleId");
employeeSearchCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("titleId.title", jobTitle));
```

When I run the code it throws an Query Exception saying `org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: TitleId of: Title`. Can anyone help me in this matter?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing here, but try changing in class `Title` the getter method name from `getId()` to `getTitleId()`.

Otherwise, I can just say that all of the examples I saw that uses `@EmbeddedId` show how to do it on the field itself, rather than on the getter as you did. So you might just as well try also to annotate the field (although Hibernate recommends not to mix method and field mapping annotations).